# Delete each Item in a foreach PHP

Tags: php

I have a table with an `foreach array of items`. I want to delete each item by a link. In the DB, the table is "`users`" and the row is "`id`".

PHP code of the table:

```
<table class="blueTable">
<thead>
<tr>
<th>ID</th>
<th>USER</th>
<th>MAIL</th>
</tr>
</thead>
<tfoot>
<tr>
<td colspan="3">
<div class="links"><a href="#">&laquo;</a> <a class="active" href="#">1</a> <a href="#">2</a> <a href="#">3</a> <a href="#">4</a> <a href="#">&raquo;</a></div>
</td>
</tr>
</tfoot>
<tbody>

<?php
$query = $db->query("SELECT * FROM users ORDER by id");
echo "<tr>";
while($row = $query->fetch_array()){
    $id = $row['id'];
    echo "<tr>"; //put <tr> opening code inside, not outside of while()
    echo "<td>".$row['id']."</td>";
    echo "<td>".$row['username']."</td>"; //remove <tr></tr>
    echo "<td>".$row['email']."</td>"; //remove <tr></tr>
    echo "<td><a href='delete($id)'>Delete</a></td>"; //remove <tr></tr>
    echo "</tr>"; //close tr only once at the end
}
?>
</tbody>
</table>
```

The function that delete the code is:

```
   function delete($id) {

        $sql = 'DELETE FROM users
                WHERE id = :id';

        $q = $this->pdo->prepare($sql);

        return $q->execute([':id' => $id]);
    }
```

I used the delete link with:

```
<a href='delete($id)'>Delete</a>
```

But didn't work. It gives the correct Id -for example (delete(5)- but didn't delete it because it shows:

```
The requested URL /sistema-login/admin/delete(5) was not found on this server.
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13840429/what-is-the-difference-between-client-side-and-server-side-programming

Comment: You are calling a function like php file. You have to know how to call function in href tag look in to this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43719877/how-to-call-php-function-from-anchor-tag)

Comment: It looks as if you assume that clicking the link, calls your Php function.  But Php isn't wired like that.  Also if you surround the delete($id) call in Php tags, you'll instantly delete those records (before any clicking/activating of the link), assuming the code works ($this looks to be a non-object reference in your function).

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if you're using some sort of framework to map url parts to function parameters, but you could something like

`<a href='delete/<?= $id ?>'>Delete</a>`

or even

`<a href='delete?id=<?= $id ?>'>Delete</a>`

And then use `$_REQUEST` to retrieve the parameter.

At least that will send the parameter to your server. I don't know how you've mapped your functions to routes, so I don't know if you're getting the right url..

Comment: I'm using localhost right now, I dont have the files in a web server. I'm not using a framework.

Comment: I'd suggest avoiding doing deletes on GET http requests.  At least do this via POST.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use this for delete record. in `while` loop

```
<a href='?id=<?= $id ?>'>Delete</a>
```

Remove function and use `$_REQUEST` like below code.

```
if(isset($_REQUEST['id']) && !empty($_REQUEST['id']))
{
    $dbh = connectDb();
    $stmt = $dbh->prepare( "DELETE FROM users WHERE id =:id" );
    $stmt->bindParam(':id', $_REQUEST['id']);
    $stmt->execute();
}
```

Comment: It shows the error: Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Using $this when not in object context in D:\Server\data\htdocs\sistema-login\functions.php:175 Stack trace: #0 D:\Server\data\htdocs\sistema-login\admin\home.php(2): include() #1 {main} thrown in D:\Server\data\htdocs\sistema-login\functions.php on line 175

Comment: Now shows:  Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function connectDb()

Comment: you can include your connection on `$dbh` variable

Comment: now shows: Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function bindParam() on bool